# How to add a <br> tag in reactjs between two strings?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using react. I want to add a line break `<br>` between strings

'No results' and  'Please try another search term.'.

I have tried `'No results.<br>Please try another search term.'`

but it does not work, I need to add the `<br>` in the html.

Any ideas how to solve it?

```js
   render() {
       let data = this.props.data;
       let isLoading = this.props.isLoading;
       let isDataEmpty = Object.entries(data).length === 0;
       let movieList = isLoading ? <Loader /> : isDataEmpty ? 'No results. Please try another search term.' :
           Object.entries(data).map((movie, index) => <MovieTile key={index} {...movie[1]} />);
       return (
           <div className='movieList'>{movieList}</div>
       );
   }
```

Answer (score 101, accepted):

You should use JSX instead of string:

```
<div>No results.<br />Please try another search term.</div>
```

> Because each jsx should have 1 wrapper I added a `<div>` wrapper for the string.

Here it is in your code:

```
render() {
   let data = this.props.data;
   let isLoading = this.props.isLoading;
   let isDataEmpty = Object.entries(data).length === 0;
   let movieList = isLoading ? <Loader /> : isDataEmpty ? <div>No results.<br />Please try another search term.</div> :
       Object.entries(data).map((movie, index) => <MovieTile key={index} {...movie[1]} />);
   return (
       <div className='movieList'>{movieList}</div>
   );
}
```

Comment: ?? Does not work for me. in the return method of render, i have<div>                    {this.state.myErrorString}</div>, where myErrorString itself begins with a <div> and ends with a </div> and has <br/> inside it, and all the tags displays !

Comment: @joedotnot does `myErrorString` is a string or a jsx object?

Comment: It is a string; For example: this.setState({myErrorString : "<div>it is a string.<br/>continue here</div>"}) which I then render inside jsx; For example:  
 render() {
  return <div>{this.state.myErrorString}</div> }

Comment: It looks like let movieList = a jsx object ! So how do i transition from a string in state into a jsx object?

Comment: This is a complete different question. Why are you using a string on the first place instead of a jsx object?

Comment: Because it never occurred to me that i can use jsx in react state (can I?). I've only used strings, arrays, objects, etc.. and reserve jsx to be used within the render part. But maybe I can proceed as per your example.. render string to a jsx wrapper first, then return the jsx wrapper

Answer (score 86):

You can use [CSS white-space](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) to solve the problem.

**React Component**

```
render() {
   message = `No results. \n Please try another search term.`;
   return (
       <div className='new-line'>{message}</div>
   );
}
```

**CSS**

```
.new-line {
  white-space: pre-line;
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
No results.
Please try another search term.
```

Comment: The best way to fix!

Comment: This should be the one and only and accepted answer

Comment: new to react, so my line of thinking is: how would i add a line break in pure html? then why do i have to create this contrived class to add a new line in react?

Comment: Nice one! I recommend this method.

Comment: @Nilesh there's no need to add a line break tag in HTML when CSS can simply show the **literal line breaks** in the content. In React, all text content is sanitized, so it's more difficult to output text (from a source you don't control) with HTML line breaks unless you do some Javascript parsing (overkill for a small problem) or you use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` (dangerous with user input).

Comment: documenting this answer.

Answer (score 19):

break text to line:

```
render() {
  ...
  <div>
    {this.props.data.split('\n').map( (it, i) => <div key={'x'+i}>{it}</div> )}
  </div>
  ...
```

Answer (score 15):

Some HTML elements such as `<img>` and `<input>` use only one tag. Such tags that belong to a single-tag element aren't an opening tag nor a closing tag. Those are self-closing tags.

In JSX, one has to include the slash. So, remove `<br>` and try `<br />`

Answer (score 10):

Here is how I got around this. Let message be the prop/variable that has the string containing line breaks to be displayed in HTML as follows:

```
message = 'No results.<br>Please try another search term.';
<div>
  {message}
</div>
```

To make this work, we need to use `\n` instead of break tag `<br>` and set the following css on the wrapper element of this message as follows:

```
message = 'No results.\nPlease try another search term.';
<div className="msg-wrapper">
  {message}
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.msg-wrapper {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
No results.
Please try another search term.
```

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want put the string inside a `<div>` you could use `<>` to do it.

Like this:

```
var text = <>This is a text in the first line;<br />this is a text in a second line</>;
```

Comment: I wanted my code directly inline but the React.Fragment was the way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

Just split text by `/n`, I do this in this way:

```
<div>
    {text.split('\n').map((item, i) => <p key={i}>{item}</p>)}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with **span**

```
return (
           <div className='movieList'><span>{movieList}</span></div>
       );
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are like in my situation and you don't want to add css, you can do that :

```
render () {
...
return (
...
<Typography component="p">
...
{(contact.lastname)?<div>Hello {contact.firstname} {contact.lastname}</div>:''}
...
</Typography>
...
);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

using `
 worked for me however i am not sure if it is the exact solution to the problem :

```js
 import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

let element = (
<div>
  <h1> Hello world</h1>
  This is just a sentence <br></br>
  But This line  should not be in the same previous line. <br></br>
  The above content proves its working. <br></br>
  npm v6.14.6 | react : {React.version} 
</div>
);

ReactDOM.render(element,document.getElementById("html-element-id"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a span tag and add block as a class.

```
Pomodoro Technique Timer <span className="block">with Bla</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing which I did is by creating a component.

```js
const EmptySpace = ({ spaceCount = 0 }) => {
  return (
    <>
      {Array.from({ length: spaceCount }, (item, index) => {
        return <br key={index} />;
      })}
    </>
  );
};

export default EmptySpace;
```

```html
<EmptySpace spaceCount={1} />
```

In your case you could do something like this:

```js
const msg = (
    <p>
      No results <EmptySpace spaceCount={2} />
      Please try another search term.
    </p>
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

can pass the content as an array
ref: https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html

**Page**

```
import MyComponent from './components/myComponent';

export default function Page() {
  return(
        <div>
            <MyComponent
              content= {["Line 1", <br/>,  "Line 2", <br/>, "Line 3"]}
            />
        </div>
  )
}
```

**React Component**

```
export default function MyComponent(props) {
  return (
    <p>
        {props.content}
    </p>
  )
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
```