# How to render a <br /> embedded in a string as a newline in JSX?

Tags: reactjs

x = `I love <br /> sports`. In the UI I want sports to be rendered in a new line.

I am using a react JSX component to achieve this.

I have tried to strip the starting single quotes and the ending single quotes as well.

I don't want to use dangerouslySetInnerHTML.

```
let x = 'I love <br /> sports' 
let y = I love <br /> sports 
render() {

    return (
       <div>
         {x}  ---- Renders as a string with no line breaks.
       </div>

       <div>
         {y}  ---------- Renders sports in a new line.
       </div>

   );

}
```

Comment: You could use some css , I would suggest flexbox

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a <br> tag in reactjs between two strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45935733/how-to-add-a-br-tag-in-reactjs-between-two-strings)

Answer (score 2):

Using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` you can display HTML tags in JSX. This is working solution of above question.

```js
class App extends React.Component{
 render(){
  let x = 'I love <br /> sports'; 
// let y = I love <br /> sports ;
  return(
    <div>
    <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
    __html: x
      }} />
</div>
  )
 }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App /> ,document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id='root' />
```

Comment: Thank you. This works except that the negatives of using dangerouslySetInnerHTML is making me think.