# Render HTML string in Azure Communication Services Hero chat application

Tags: azure-communication-services

I am trying to render html string into the chat application based on Azure Communication Services. The boilerplate code is taken from Azure Samples GitHub repo https://github.com/Azure-Samples/communication-services-web-chat-hero.

I have the string in format:
`"str1</br>str2</br>str3</br>"`.

What I want is I want to render this string as html in ChatArea component of the app so that it looks like

```
str1
str2
str3
```

I have also set SendMessageOptions.type to 'html' in sendMessageHelper method in sideEffects.ts file but still getting the output as string only. Only difference is now I am getting sanitized string without `/` in `br` tags.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

By default this sample trivially assume messages are one-line strings and react doesn't automatically handle `\n` characters or `<br />`.

To do multiline, inside [ChatThread](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/communication-services-web-chat-hero/blob/c15cac6fda70a60f8e67f9294f6c2c6ea002bfab/Chat/ClientApp/src/components/ChatThread.tsx#L287) where the messages are rendered, you will want to ensure the appropriate JSX is generated:

To support multiline where lines are seperated by `\n` you will need to update

```js
{renderHyperlink(message.content.message)}
```

to something like:

```js
{message.content.message.split(/\n/g).map((line: string) => <p>{renderHyperlink(line)}</p>)}
```

More information and other solutions can be found here: [How to add a <br> tag in reactjs between two strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45935733/how-to-add-a-br-tag-in-reactjs-between-two-strings/45935795)

To support rendering *any arbitrary HTML* from messages you will need to adapt this line to load the message string as html. **However using arbitrarily sent html can be dangerous in an application**, a malicious user could embed malicious scripts html or scripts, so avoid doing this. For more information search up Cross-Site Scripting attacks: https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/xss/.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I surely will try this and will get back to you.