# Break in paragraph

Tags: html, reactjs, tailwind-css, tailwind-ui

So for some reason i'm not able to create a broken line inside the paragraph such that I can get a new line... I'm using tailwind with react.

```
<p className="mt-3 text-base text-gray-300 sm:mt-5 sm:text-xl lg:text-lg xl:text-xl">
Transform the way you interact with your customers. Collect valuable, actionable and credible feedback.</p>
```

So I've tried all these solutions, but I get errors.

1.

```
<p className="mt-3 text-base text-gray-300 sm:mt-5 sm:text-xl lg:text-lg xl:text-xl">
    Transform the way you interact with your customers. <br> Collect valuable, actionable and credible feedback.</p>
```

2. 

```
<p className="mt-3 text-base text-gray-300 sm:mt-5 sm:text-xl lg:text-lg xl:text-xl">
    Transform the way you interact with your customers. <br> Collect valuable, actionable and credible feedback.</br> </p>
```

3. 

```
<p className="mt-3 text-base text-gray-300 sm:mt-5 sm:text-xl lg:text-lg xl:text-xl">
    Transform the way you interact with your customers. {"\n"} Collect valuable, actionable and credible feedback.</p>
```

Comment: The first one seems correct to me, what error do you get?

Comment: I get this error:

https://codepen.io/SermadAlladin/pen/mdpyrZQ

And when i close the tag </br> it still messes up.

Comment: try with a self closing tag <br/>

Comment: Oh well, that worked!

Answer (score 1):

Relate to the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45935733/how-to-add-a-br-tag-in-reactjs-between-two-strings#:%7E:text=You%20should%20use%20JSX%20instead%20of%20string%3A)

Every html tags should be closed, remember this is jsx not html. Every component should be closed.

```
<br> in jsx ->  <br/>
<input> in jsx -> <input />
```

You can read about jsx more [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html)

Comment: I still get an error when i use the closing tag.

Comment: ```
<p className="mt-3 text-base text-gray-300 sm:mt-5 sm:text-xl lg:text-lg xl:text-xl">
    Transform the way you interact with your customers. <br/> Collect valuable, actionable and credible feedback.<br/> </p>
```

Comment: That should be your example. So if you want to write two breaks inside p just write them 
<br/>  <br/>, you can write as many as you want but closing should happen at the end <br/>. check If you are doing so, if not please write a sandbox so I can see it, I will kindly help you.

Answer (score 0):

The first one it's correct, just use a self closing tag so you won't get that error

```
<p className="mt-3 text-base text-gray-300 sm:mt-5 sm:text-xl lg:text-lg 
xl:text-xl">
Transform the way you interact with your customers. <br/> Collect valuable, 
actionable and credible feedback.</p>
```

Comment: I still get an error when i close the tage like this.

Answer (score 0):

I have same style worked inside `div`

```
  <div className="text-lg text-center font-semibold mt-4">
        Breaking after this 
        <br /> new line
      </div>
```