# JSON.parse works only after re-render in React/Next

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, next.js

I have an object called organizationCustomizationOptions, which is a String. If I print that string without parsing it, I will get something like `'{"name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"}'`

Please note that I'm changing the actual JSON which is something way more complex to this simple example from W3 Schools. The only difference might be that the real JSON contains line breaks and HTML tags inside. I've already dealt with that by adding a 

`dangerouslySetInnerHTML` prop inside the

tag

 into which I want to put a text in and [my own CSS classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35351706/how-to-render-a-multi-line-text-string-in-react). The **line breaks and HTML tags inside the string might be out of scope** of this problem, but just wanted to give the info just in case.

If I try to `console.log(JSON.parse(organizationCustomizationOptions))` I get `SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0`. However If I comment this line, render the app, and then uncomment, everything works perfectly.

This is obviously not happening with the simple object in the example. It's happening with the big, complex object that has line breaks and HTML tags inside.

Comment: I think `organizationCustomizationOptions` is already JSON formatted not as a string

Comment: Does this answer your question: [uncaught syntaxerror unexpected token U JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13022178/uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-u-json)? Make sure the value you're passing to `JSON.parse` is not `undefined`.