# replace a character in a string with a new line in react js

Tags: reactjs, string, replace, newline

In my application i receive a string where i need to make that into two lines...when there is a @ character in that string....everything after that @ should come in the next line..

like if my string is 'My name is example @ My hobby is'
it should display like My name is example
My hobby is

tried using '\n' but it dnt work...

```
    var result= data.referenceNo.replace("@",'\n');
    <tr>{result}</tr>
```

@ character is getting replaced but its not getting into next line

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35351843/941240

Comment: Please add a CSS style `.new-line {
  white-space: pre-line;
}` to your `tr`